# Sending facebook direct messages

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to send direct message using the facebook graph api? I’ve read old posts that suggest this is not possible but wasn’t sure whether this is still the case today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/ but this messaging systems seems to be for reading the messages only.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses open protocol **XMPP**

more here: http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=297991732130

You have to those one of many [clients](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) or [libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) or write your own to communicate with facebook..